# Controlling link wrapped item in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container that is set to `display: flex` inside this container are items that are wrapped with links. I'd like to control the items with their div class names rather than their `a` attribute. Here's my code:

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.container a {
  background-color: red;
  width: 48%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="google.com"><div class="item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div></a>
  <a href="google.com"><div class="item">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page.</div></a>
</div>
```

This works perfectly, however, I want to replace `.container a` with the div class name item. The reason for this is when maintaining the code I think it would confuse the person looking over my CSS. How can I make it so I can replace the selector `.container a` with `.item` and it still working the same? Note: The entire div block must be a link. Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bd4gmxq7/)

Comment: if you dont want to use `a` tag then assign them a class attribute and use the class name instead

Comment: @FacundoCorradini Having a tags outside the div isn't valid HTML?

Comment: why don't you just add the classes to the A items. While we're at it, why don't just drop the divs altogether?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the classes to your A tags. And even drop the divs altogether.

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  /*width: 100%; by default*/
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: wrap; /* has no effect since you're using % for flex-items width */
}

.item {
  background-color: red;
  width: 48%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="item" href="google.com">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </a>
  <a class="item" href="google.com">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page.</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like this, by moving the `a` tag inside the `div` by doing so you can target them using the `div` class `.item`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><a href="google.com">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        </a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="google.com">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page.</a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This will make only the text linked and not the background though

Comment: What if you target them with 

`a > .item {}`

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the class names to the `a` tags instead of the `div`s (or to both, if the DIVs need to keep the classes)